# the Message ID for submit_sm and delivery is not the same

Tags: smpp, restcomm

### Context :

I want to search the submitted message (submit_sm) for a given delivered message (deliver_sm).
the problem that I can't find a matching between the submitted message and the received delivery message from
the Cassandra table Message_DD_MM_YY.

### Environment:

I'm using restcomm 7.0.49, I'm using also restcomm-smpp-simulator to simulate emse server systemID(test) , and to simulate esme client I'm using SMPPSIM simulator systemID(smppclient1).

### Scenario

I’m sending an MT message from test to smppclient1,and I want to match this message with its delivery receipt.

Expected result :that the messageID of the delivery receipt message_text will be the same as the messageID generated in the first submit_sm (between esme server(test) and restComm ).

Result that i got : the delivery receipt contains the id of the second submit sm (between restcomm and esme client (smppclient1)).so I can't match the message with its delivery.

I attached a detail flow graph and a dump traffic of wireshark, also a file "message.csv" containing the content of the cassandra table "MESSAGE_xxx" during the pervious scenario in the link below.

[image: the flow graph]

[link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/restcomm/CoV2ETG7Es4)

Comment: It's quite unclear what exactly you're sending and receiving but if you got a `submit_sm_resp` with `message_id = 67`, and later got a `deliver_sm` with `message_id = 67` then where is the problem? It's not guaranteed that you'll get `deliver_sm` PDUs in the same order as you sent the `submit_sm` PDUs, so it's quite possible to first receive a `deliver_sm` for a `submit_sm` that was sent last.

Comment: thank's @pilsetnieks  for your respons .I  edit my publication

Comment: Ok, so it's much clearer now. To be honest, this is the first time I hear about that restcomm thing but it seems that it's simply not doing its job properly. If there's some intermediate software handling everything, it should either not change a damn thing, or if it does, keep track of all the IDs, and provide the endpoint with the correct one. I hope it's a behavior that you can change with some configuration settings but if not, it sounds like a pretty serious issue.